# Import excel/csv file using ethercalc API

Tags: php, excel, curl

I want to import an excel/csv file into ethercalc using curl not drop file.
Which url of ethercalc I need to use to PUT a file to?
Here is the open source website
https://ethercalc.net/

Answer (score 2):

As of today's version, EtherCalc 0.20150103.1 now supports importing multi-sheet Excel (and OpenDocument Spreadsheets) via this REST API:

```
curl -i -X PUT --data-binary @file.xlsx http://HOST/=file.xlsx
```

If you only need to import the first worksheet in the Excel file, this should also work:

```
curl -i -X PUT --data-binary @file.xlsx http://HOST/_/file
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

There is an API docs with examples for different programming languages: http://docs.ethercalc.apiary.io/

BTW you could use next command for importing csv to spreadsheet:

```
curl --include --request PUT \ 
--header "Content-Type: text/csv" \ 
--data @table.csv http://server/_/table_name
```

I'm not sure that you could import xls file, but you can convert it to socialcalc format and import after that.

Comment: Could you show me the documentation to convert xls to socialcalc format. I tried but not success yet.